# ordering in Jedis zrangeByScore

Tags: java, redis

I'm working with sorted sets in Java, and I want to get all elements with scores between min/max as an ordered list from min to max score. However, the Jedis implementation returns a Set, and I don't see anywhere in the documentation that guarantees it to be ordered
`jedis.zrangeByScore(key, min, max);`

The expected return of ZRANGEBYSCORE should be a list or ordered set, is there any way to do this in the Java Jedis implmentation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **zrangebyscorewithscores** which returns the results as **Set**  scores along with values, thereon scores can be used for sorting the results.